# pandas how to duplicate rows in a dataframe with uneven columns, only where data exists in specific column and form new dataframe with even columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe of uneven data that I would like to normalise into rows so that I can group the data. The first x columns are filled and of fixed length but then there will be an un undefined amount of further columns. This data is read from a csv file where each symbol can have multiple or no hosts.

What I want to end up with is grouped data in the format:

`{"host1": [sym1, sym2, sym3], "host3": [sym5]}`

I've set the empty cells to "" and the end of my dataframe where the un-even data looks like is:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sym1 | host1 | host2 | "" |
| sym2 | host2 | host1 | "" |
| sym3 | "" | "" | "" |
| sym4 | host1 | host2 | "" |
| sym5 | host1 | host2 | host3 |
| sym6 | host1 | host2 | "" |

what I want is a dataframe that looks like this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| sym1 | host1 |
| sym1 | host2 |
| sym2 | host2 |
| sym2 | host1 |
| sym4 | host1 |
| sym4 | host2 |
| sym5 | host1 |
| sym5 | host2 |
| sym5 | host3 |
| sym6 | host1 |
| sym6 | host2 |

Answer (score 2):

You make it more complicated by making those empty values `'""'`.

IIUC:

```
df.mask(df.eq('""')).melt('A').rename(columns={'value': 'B'})[['A', 'B']].dropna()

       A      B
0   sym1  host1
1   sym2  host2
3   sym4  host1
4   sym5  host1
5   sym6  host1
6   sym1  host2
7   sym2  host1
9   sym4  host2
10  sym5  host2
11  sym6  host2
16  sym5  host3
```

OR

```
df.mask(df.eq('""')).set_index('A').stack().reset_index('A', name='B')

      A      B
B  sym1  host1
C  sym1  host2
B  sym2  host2
C  sym2  host1
B  sym4  host1
C  sym4  host2
B  sym5  host1
C  sym5  host2
D  sym5  host3
B  sym6  host1
C  sym6  host2
```

I'd prefer

```
dat = [
    {'A': a, 'B': b}
    for a, *B in zip(*map(df.get, df))
    for b in B if b != '""' and b
]

pd.DataFrame(dat)

       A      B
0   sym1  host1
1   sym1  host2
2   sym2  host2
3   sym2  host1
4   sym4  host1
5   sym4  host2
6   sym5  host1
7   sym5  host2
8   sym5  host3
9   sym6  host1
10  sym6  host2
```

Comment: How would I expand this if there were other colums in the dataframe, that I'd want to return in the new rows? i.e. i have columns A, 0,1,2,3,...# B, C, D where A and 0 to # are completely filled with no Nan or "" values? 

For Example:
`d = {"sym": ["sym1", "sym2"], "i_type": ["s", "s"], "isin": ["blah", "blah"], "A": ["host1", "host1"], "B": ["host2", ""]}`